# STM32 CAN loop back mode

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus, hal

I am starting a basic use of HAL drivers for loop back mode of CAN peripheral in STM32F103xx MCU. Base on the user manual of the MCU, when the transmission is fully accomplished and the data becomes available in the CAN bus, TME, RQCP and TXOK bits of the CAN_TSR Register are set by the hardware showing that the corresponding mail box has become empty and the transmission is done successfully.

When I debug the following program, none of the mentioned changes happen in the CAN_TSR register. I can only see that the TME bit gets set that means a mail box is provided for transmission but never transmitted.

This piece of my code causes an infinitive loop in the program:

```
while(HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan, TxMailbox));
```

Could you please explain me what is my problem and what I should do. Thanks for your ideas.

This is the full code:

```
#include "main.h"
CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void Can_TX(void);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

int main(void)
{
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();
  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  LCD1602_Begin4BIT(RS_GPIO_Port, RS_Pin, E_Pin, D4_GPIO_Port, D4_Pin, D5_Pin, D6_Pin, D7_Pin);
  LCD1602_print("Sending...");
  Can_TX();
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++);
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_CAN_Init(void)
{
  hcan.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan.Init.Prescaler = 1;
  hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_LOOPBACK;
  hcan.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_13TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;
  hcan.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, RS_Pin|E_Pin|D4_Pin|D5_Pin|D6_Pin|D7_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RS_Pin|E_Pin|D4_Pin|D5_Pin|D6_Pin|D7_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void Can_TX(void)
{
  CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef TxHeader;
  uint8_t our_message[5] = {'H','E','L','L','O'};
  uint32_t TxMailbox;
  TxHeader.DLC = 1;
  TxHeader.StdId = 0x65D;
  TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
  TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
  HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, our_message, &TxMailbox);
  if(HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, our_message, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  while(HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan, TxMailbox));
  LCD1602_print("Message is sent");
}

void Error_Handler(void) { }
```

Comment: Contact your vendor and hope they don't charge you $$$ :)

Answer (score 6):

I may have additional information that could be useful, on how **proper bit timings settings resolved my issue** , and made my tx message leave the mailbox without error.

I wanted to test my CAN Peripheral with the loopback function however the message was stuck in the mailbox.

Upon careful reading of the documentation, I first found that I forgot `HAL_CAN_Start()` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61854946/14621482) by [HelpingHand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3052687/helpinghand), and indeed, flag INRQ was still on. (It is set by `HAL_CAN_Init`.)

After this modification, I was not seeing any message on the receiving side and was not sure that it was properly sent. Looking into the cause, I noted that `RQCPx` was set to 1, meaning regardless of success or error, the transmission request was completed, `TXOKx` at 0 and `TERRx` at 1, meaning there was a transmission error. The `LEC`(last error code) bits from `CAN_ESR` (error status registers) were set to 101, or, according to the documentation, bit dominant error.

I did not exactly understand what this means, a clarification may be welcomed to better understand how to make the message properly leave the mailbox, but stumbling across [this thread from st community](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkeMe/stm32f103-can-transmit-error-bit-dominant-error), I understood that using random timing settings will not have a good outcome. (It seems obvious now).

So using [this CAN Bit Time Calculation](http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/), I figured out the correct settings. For that, I needed my `APB1 peripheral clocks` frequency and the desired baudrate (for me those are 24MHz and 125kbps). I used the preferred `sample point` and `SJW` values recommended by the tool which are 87.5% and 1. The following table is then generated :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENshf.png

It is then pretty simple to fill STM32CubeIDE fields of the bit timings parameters :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1q61.png

And tada, the `TXOKx` is at 1 and `TERRx` at 0.

As a bonus, here is a small piece of code that retrieves the `LEC` that I wrote. It is not intended to be used in a fully functional application, it is just for testing.

```
//adds a message to transmit and obtains "allocated" TxMailbox
HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(hcan, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox);

//waiting for message to leave
while(HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan1, TxMailbox));

//waiting for transmission request to be completed by checking RQCPx
while( !(hcan->Instance->TSR & ( 0x1 << (7 * ( TxMailbox - 1 )))));

//checking if there is an error at TERRx, may be done with TXOKx as well (i think)
if ((hcan->Instance->TSR & ( 0x8 << (7 * ( TxMailbox - 1 ))))){
    //error is described in ESR at LEC last error code
    uint8_t error_code = ( hcan->Instance->ESR & 0x70 ) >> 4;
    //000: No Error
    //001: Stuff Error
    //010: Form Error
    //011: Acknowledgment Error
    //100: Bit recessive Error
    //101: Bit dominant Error
    //110: CRC Error
    //111: Set by software
    while (1);
}
```

I hope my answer was not too much of the topic and qualifies as an acceptable, first, contribution according to Stack Overflow policy.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed analysis, it saved me lots of time and anguish.

Answer (score 1):

- > [...] when the transmission is fully accomplished and the data becomes available in the CAN bus, TME, RQCP and TXOK bits of the CAN_TSR Register are set by the hardware showing that the corresponding mail box has become empty and the transmission is done successfully.
  >
  > When I debug the following program, none of the mentioned changes happen in the CAN_TSR register.

  The CAN peripheral ("bxCAN") of STM32F103xx comprises three TX FIFOs.
  Hence there are three instances of `( TMEx, RQCPx, TXOKx )` to check - just to make sure.
- > I can only see that the TME bit gets set that means a mail box is provided for transmission but never transmitted.

  There seems to be a mistake in the interpretation of TME bits in CAN_TSR:
  As you can verify in sec. 24.9.2 (pages 677-8) of the 
  [STM32F103 reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf),
  TME bits are *"set by hardware when no transmit request is pending for mailbox"*.
  Hence, if one finds those bits *set* then the transmission appears to be already over.
- If the transmission remains pending, it might have stuck due to error conditions.
  What about the error counters (REC/TEC) in register `CAN_ESR`?

  If no receiver is listening, a CAN transmitter will go into error modes because the acknowledge bits of receivers don't reach the transmitter.
  The code sample doesn't show any enable-GPIO instructions for CAN pins.
  This should be OK with loopback mode, but I have never tried this out myself.
- Transmission may be pending because the bxCAN component still remains in its *initialization mode*, see sec. 24.4.1 (page 657) in the reference manual.
  Then, software has to trigger transition into *normal mode*.
  I'm not sure if `HAL_CAN_Init()` includes this.
- The variable `TxMailbox` is never initialised in user code.
  If it is assigned by function `HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage()`, this is fine.
  If not, `HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending()` will poll at a wrong mailbox address (maybe forever).
- The function `HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage()` is called twice (once discarding its return value, the second time checking it.
  This is likely to cause other problems (multiple-TX), but I don't see a relation to the present no-TX problem.
- `DLC` is set to 1, but the message is 5 bytes long.
  When the transmission starts working, it will only transmit an `'H'`, but `'E','L','L','O'` will be missing.

---

**Update:** I checked the 
[documentation of STM32CubeF1 HAL](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00154093-description-of-stm32f1-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf).
Section 9.2 (page 92) describes how to initialise CAN through the HAL driver from ST:

1. Run `__HAL_RCC_CANx_CLK_ENABLE()`.

   - I don't see this in the code sample. To be checked...
2. Initialize CAN peripheral using `HAL_CAN_Init()`.

   - This is done in the code sample. OK.
3. Configure the reception filters using `HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter()`.

   - This is missing, but I don't think it is the reason why TX doesn't work.
4. Start the CAN module using `HAL_CAN_Start()`.

   - I think this is the missing function call. I haven't checked its code, but I guess that this function also takes care of the `INRQ`/`SLEEP` flags.
     **This is the best candidate for the origin of the problem!**
5. Affects `HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage()` and others.

   - But this in line with the code sample. OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to add `HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan);` in the `CAN1_x` function.